# UITableViewAutomaticDimension is working but how do I get the frame Size the autolayout set it to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

My Question might sound strange but somehow I need to ask this. So I have UITableViewAutomaticDimension set on my both Section Header and Rows which is working like a charm. But somehow I am playing with constraints which changes my Section Header dynamically(The whole frame and constraints **NOT** Content when the Table scrolls. IS there a way to get the size or frame that was set to my Section Header while using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

I am not looking for suggestions like why should I not change my constraints at run time. Please help if I can find the auto-layout size set to the headers after my table was loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the `bounds` of the view in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)` from `UITableViewDelegate` and that will be the size that the automatic dimension calculated. Same goes for cells in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.